# Why variable doesn't clear its value

Tags: javascript, object

I have next code:

```
let list = {
  value: 1,
  next: {
    value: 2,
    next: {
      value: 3,
      next: {
        value: 4,
        next: null
      }
    }
  }
};
```

Why doesn't the following code delete the value of the secondList variable?

```
let secondList = list.next.next;
list.next.next = null;
```

Shouldn't the secondList have reference to the same object to which we assigned null?

Comment: It's a reference to the object from _before_ you assigned `null`. You've only changed what `list.next.next` refers to.

Comment: This might help: https://javascript.info/object-copy

Comment: Or https://pythontutor.com/visualize.html#code=let%20list%20%3D%20%7B%0A%20%20value%3A%201,%0A%20%20next%3A%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20value%3A%202,%0A%20%20%20%20next%3A%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20value%3A%203,%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20next%3A%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20value%3A%204,%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20next%3A%20null%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%7D%0A%20%20%20%20%7D%0A%20%20%7D%0A%7D%3B%0Alet%20secondList%20%3D%20list.next.next%3B%0Alist.next.next%20%3D%20null%3B&cumulative=false&curInstr=0&heapPrimitives=nevernest&mode=display&origin=opt-frontend.js&py=js&rawInputLstJSON=%5B%5D&textReferences=false

Comment: No. `list.next.next` points (in principle) at the memory location where some object `X` is stored. `secondList` points to the same memory location. `list.next.next = null` changes, where `list.next.next` is pointing to, but not the content of that memory location. So `secondList` is still pointing to the same memory location, which still holds the original object `X`

Comment: because it's a pointer to the same location in the computer memory. `secondList = list.next.next` is **not** a new "thing" at all, but only a new variable name which points to the exact same place in memory.

Comment: "_Shouldn't the secondList have reference to the same object_" Yes, but the references are not the same.

Answer (score 2):

The value of `list.next.next` is a reference to an object.

`let secondList = list.next.next;` copies the reference to that object to `secondList`.

`list.next.next = null` replaces the original reference to the object with `null`.

It doesn't delete or modify the object itself. The value of `secondList` is unchanged. Since there remains a reference to the object (in `secondList`), the object is not garbage collected.